# Removing old Linux versions on GRUB 2 via Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: 10.04, kernel, package-management, grub2

I have read in other sites and this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions) about removing old entries using Synaptic Package Manager but when I open it I can't find anything when I type linux-image or numbers.

EDIT:
Yes Ubuntu Tweak worked, but anyone knows why I can't find those in Synaptic Package Manager? if it matters I use Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure you actually have old Linux kernels to remove?

Comment: @root45 yes I have whole screen, and if I want to reach windows it takes a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to uninstall the old kernels from [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), is safer and easier.
[image]
(sorry the photo is in Greek)

Or read this information if want to do it manually.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275