# Files are piling up in /usr/src/. How can I stop this?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I have been having many serious system issues over the past few weeks and have been scratching my head as to why. I've now worked out that this problem is having no inodes left on the root partition

```
$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       732960 724565    8395   99% /
udev            125179    518  124661    1% /dev
tmpfs           127001    464  126537    1% /run
none            127001      4  126997    1% /run/lock
none            127001      8  126993    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7      5234688 144639 5090049    3% /home
```

What is the cause? I've found that 400K of those are in use in /usr/src

```
$ ls /usr/src
linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-33
linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-33-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-26              linux-headers-3.2.0-33-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-35
linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-27              linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-36
linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-29              linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-39
linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-30              linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-40
linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-31              linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-41
linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-32              linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-43
linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
```

Surely not all of these are actually needed? I've tried apt-get autoremove but it leaves them all be. I don't want to remove them manually, but this is crippling my machine. They also take up almost 2G of the 11G system partition that is getting full (>80%) aside from the inode issue.

How can I safely remove the headers that are not needed?

Comment: Have you tried removing the packages that provide those?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59790/removing-old-linux-versions-on-grub-2-via-synaptic-package-manager explains how to do it from GUI

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can search for packages that own these files using

```
dpkg -S /usr/src/*
```

Check your current kernel version

```
uname --kernel-release
```

And remove all old kernel (`linux-image-*`) and header packages (`linux-headers-*`) that are **not currently used** but are still installed.

You can also mark these packages as automatically installed and they should get autoremoved.

Comment: And how do you mark these packages as automatically installed?

Comment: `apt-mark auto packageName`

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-mark.8.html

Answer (score 26):

This should work:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You can read more at the [AptGet How-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Comment: Probably the best answer here.

Comment: OP clearly says he tried this and it didn't work...

Comment: It didn't work first. It worked after `apt-get clean` & `apt-get autoclean`