# Repair grub after Ubuntu partition move/resize - BootRepair log

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

I have spent today moving/resizing my Ubuntu 16.04 partition on my dual boot T420s laptop.
I believe all has worked well, except that (as I was warned might happen), it has broken boot.
I have run BootRepair - which went exactly as the guide suggested it should. I installed Grub on both partitions.
After BootRepair, I get the ubuntu-style boot options screen. Windows will boot normally, but Ubuntu spends ages on its launch screen, before giving this error:

> [0.941240] tmp_tis 00.05: A TPM error (6) occurred attempting to read
>   a pcr value Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in ...

As suggested, I am putting a link to the pasted output from boot repair [here](http://paste2.org/CL1pIFEI), in the hope that someone will put me right.

Also, in case it is useful, here is how Windows Disk Management sees my HDD. Somehow even the BIOS won't see my Ubuntu Boot USB any more, so I can't get GParted running.
[Windows DiskManagement partition info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn34w.png)
Thanks for looking!

UPDATE INFORMATION - in case this is helpful to anyone with a similar problem: I managed to get Ubuntu to boot from an older kernel option through the 'Advanced Ubuntu' option in Grub. From this point I have been able to tidy things up to the point where all works as normal.

1: During my attempts to grow the Ubuntu partition leftwards (into space recovered by shrinking the Windows partition), I had at one point made the unallocated space into a separate partition, thinking to us it for /home. As part of that process I had had to edit fstab, adding a new mount UUID. I failed to remove this when I deleted that partition and took the space into the main Ubuntu partition. Once I was into Ubuntu I got rid of that.

2: 'housecleaning kernels' led me to a package called 'bikeshed' (search linuxg.net - I'm not allowed to post any more links), which has a tool called {purge-old-kernels} which not only removes outdated kernel images, but the rebuilds the 'Grub' listing too.

3: And now everything smells of roses!

Comment: It looks like Boot-Repair reinstalled grub to MBR of sda drive. You do not install grub to a PBR like sda5. So does it boot now? You also need to houseclean kernels. Best to have done most of that before upgrading.

Comment: The machine will boot, yes - through Grub - but Windows is the only option that works.
So, I should re-run Boot-Repair and only install into the MBR of sda? 
And before that, I should 'houseclean kernels' - except that I have no idea what this means in practice. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens booting Ubuntu then? What video card? Have you tried booting recovery mode boot option in grub (In advanced options). With 16.04 kernel update is better, it should only keep 2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels But your old kernels that should have mostly been deleted before upgrade, may require manual removal if not still in dpkg. But parts are in various places. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this

Comment: It was advanced options that got me back in. Lenovo Thinkpad T420s - integrated graphics I think. purge-old-kernels did the housecleaning for me. Thanks