# Lubuntu install keeps growing in size - and its scary

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, gparted, root

Lubuntu 20.04LTS here, and I have Lubuntu installed on a 16GB flash drive.The space used in the root partition has jumped from 4 GB after clean install to 5, then to 6 and now to 9GB.

I have a 13GB root partition, and the rest are swap and boot-related.

It isn't that I haven't installed anything, but all I've done is - Install the KDE theme, while removing the other themes, installed the Nvidia driver, install Gparted, and add bcmwl drivers, and thats about it.

I'm asking experienced and intermediate users if with my type of things installed, (Nvidia drivers wont exceed 1GB , maybe 2 ?) it is reasonable to expect the OS size to balloon up by 4GB in 3 days of installation, or if there's something to look out for.

Why is Lubuntu growing like Windows after an update ?

Comment: The recommended minimum size for an install of any 20.04 desktop is 25GB, so why are you worrying. You've tagged `gparted` (a GTK3 app) so it'll cause more libraries to be installed compared to the default KDE Partition Manager, so the increase in size is not unusual (consider software choices in your selection if it matters, Lubuntu is a Qt5 based desktop environment so GTK3 apps will require more to be installed..)

Comment: @guiverc right, but is there any rational way to justify the increases that I'm seeing ? from 4, to 6 to now 9. 4 to 9 is a more than double gain.

Comment: To me the question is off-topic; https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask as being very opinion related given no specifics only vague assertions were provided. nvidia drivers are large (the ISOs are much larger when they are included and that's squashed unlike what's eventually installed on the system) but I personally worry little about footprint on disk until it nears wiki recommended size which Lubuntu doesn't..

Comment: @guiverc its a simple question, not at all opinionated, very specific. I'm asking experienced and intermediate users if with my type of things installed, (Nvidia drivers wont exceed 1GB , maybe 2 ?) it is reasonable to expect the OS size to balloon up by more than double in 3 days of installation.

Comment: Are you housecleaning? Log files grow and are only necessary if you have issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace & https://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this & https://askubuntu.com/questions/301466/files-are-piling-up-in-usr-src-how-can-i-stop-this

Comment: I have done a fresh install 3 days ago. I just now used Bleachbit, freed up 1.4GB space. Previously occupied : 9.6 GB -->  Now: 8.2GB

Comment: Did you install lots of snap apps?

Comment: not even one,@ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: I think the used drive space is normal for the way you use your installed system. The easy solution is to get a bigger drive (at least double size, 32 GB). Otherwise you must be very restrictive, select carefully what to install and download and spend time to houseclean the system according to the useful links in oldfred's comment.

Comment: @sudodus I intend to get a bigger drive but in my region, there is a strict lockdown due to covid, due to which amazon will not deliver until it is lifted.

Comment: So until then, please be very restrictive also in this context, select carefully what to install and download and spend time to houseclean the system. I wish that you and your USB drive will be stay healthy :-)

Comment: FYI:   You mention installing a KDE theme... KDE uses both Qt5 & KF5 where as Lubuntu uses only Qt5, so don't forget using KDE things can introduce KF5 packages onto your system (which may also be needed in memory; ie. using resources in disk & whilst in operation). You weren't specific as to what you installed; so we cannot see what it uses or relies on (what I guess I referred to as *opinion* last time) so don't forget to make allowances for what users install (without checking the requirements)... why the suggested minimum is 25GB  (uses don't read *requirements* before install)